# Q: LM833N acting weird above 9V

Tags: amplifier

I have a quick question as to why my LM833N is behaving as such.

Any time I try to power the amplifer with 9V or over nothing happens, its just a flat line on its output like its turned off or something.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCCn1N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is whats happening when Input 9.58V
[image]

Comment: if I'm reading this right, it works fine below 9V?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning: if you're providing the same supply to the OPA350 as to the LM833N, you've fried your OPA350; its absolute maximum supply voltage is 7V

Comment: @Felthry  well like 5V yeah, to low obviously it doesnt turn on. Oscilloscope measures 0Vs I am not providing it with the same voltage, but good reminder thank you

Comment: @jsotola answered above wont let me tag you in for some reason

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but C3 looks very large; is that correct?

Comment: C3 is large due to not attenuating any signals at the output as it makes a high pass filter with the speaker

Comment: How big is this "speaker?"  Anything more than maybe an earphone is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Its just headphones, what do you think its the cause of this though? The data sheet says it can go up to 18+/- ? VCC @JRE

Comment: I figured it out whats causing it, its my rheostat in the feedback loop.

Comment: The rheostat is used to control gain? If so then it should go to the LM833's inverting input, not to C2.

Comment: Sorry, I missed wrote the schematic

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the LM833 opamp as a power amplifier that has a 16 ohms load? The datasheet shows a typical load of 10 thousand ohms and a minimum load of 2 thousand ohms.
You are severely overloading the poor thing.

Comment: I understand, but its going to be used going into a pre amplifier stage anyways. That amp is not going to be used to drive anything. Just wanted to hear the sound quality up to that stage